# How to handle a null value in Flutter Model Factory

Tags: flutter

I have a json that I need to parse and return to a `FutureBuilder`. The problem I have is in this line: `final meta = jsonDecode(parsedJson!['metadata']);` Sometimes `metadata` is null and it throws this error `Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. What is the best way to handle that?

The metadata contains an image url that I want to use in a grid. So if possible, a default metadata object should be created with a default image url.

```
class Data {
  final int total;
  final MetaData metadata;

  Data({
    required this.total,
    required this.metadata,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(parsedJson) {
    final meta = jsonDecode(parsedJson!['metadata']);

    MetaData md = MetaData.fromJson(meta);

    return Data(
      total: parsedJson['total'] ?? 0,
      metadata: md,
    );
  }
}

class MetaData {
  final String image;

  MetaData({
    required this.image,
  });

  factory MetaData.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return MetaData(
      image: json['image'] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

*** EDIT my solution

I decided to do something like this. And I'll just populate the object string as needed. Would this be ok?

```
  factory Data.fromJson(parsedJson) {
    var metadataString = parsedJson['metadata'];

    metadataString ??=
        "{\"image\":\"https://somewebsite.com/1.png\"}";

    var meta = jsonDecode(metadataString);

    MetaData md = MetaData.fromJson(meta);

    return Data(
      total: parsedJson['total'] ?? 0,
      metadata: md,
    );
  }
```

Comment: yeah it would be ok, otherwise you can go with null safe validation and follow my answer

Comment: thank you for commenting and answering. I will use what I wrote because I do need a default image and I'll just set it here. maybe some other data too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether your metadata is null or not. And follow this code snippet

```
    metadata = json['metadata'] != null
        ? Metadata.fromJson(json['metadata'])
        : null;
```